# How to create a function to drag a node in tree structure using perl win32::GUI?

Tags: perl

How to drag and drop a node in one position to another using perl win32::gui?
Is it possible? I am creating a tree view and adding a node by dynamically. After completion of a tree structure I need to move one node position to another by dragging. I have mentioned the code below.

```
use strict;
use Win32::GUI;

my $main_window=Win32::GUI::Window->new(
        -name => 'Main',
        -text => 'Main Window',
        -left => 375,
        -top  => 200,
        -width =>510,#370,
        -height =>480,
        -background => [177,175,175],
        -dialogui   => 1,
        -maximizebox => 0,
  );

 $C = new Win32::GUI::Cursor("harrow.cur");

  Win32::GUI::SetCursor($C);

  $B1 = new Win32::GUI::Bitmap("node.bmp");
  $B2 = new Win32::GUI::Bitmap("node_sel.bmp");

    $IL = new Win32::GUI::ImageList(26, 26, 0, 2, 30);
    $IL->Add($B1, 0);
    $IL->Add($B2, 0);

   my $TV=$main_window->AddTreeView(
        -name      => "myTree",
        -text      => "",
        -width     => 220,
        -height    => 238,
        -left      => 260,
        -top       => 198,
        -lines     => 1,
        -rootlines => 1,
        -buttons   => 1,
        -visible   => 1,
        -imagelist => $IL,
        -editlabels =>1,
        -singleexpand => 1,
        -disabledragdrop =>0,

    );
   my $IndentWin = new GUI::Window(
        -text   => "Treeview Indent",
        -name   => "IndentWin",
        -width  => 200,
        -height => 100,
        -left   => 10,
        -top    => 10,
        -background=>[190,190,190],
    );

    my $IndentVal = $IndentWin->AddLabel(
        -text => "Indent value = ".$TV->Indent(),

        -name => "IndentVal",
        -left => 10,
        -top  => 10,
    );

   my $IndentNew = $IndentWin->AddTextfield(
        -text   =>  $TV->Indent(),
        -name   =>  "IndentNew",
        -left   =>  10,
        -top    => 40,
        -width  => 100,
        -height => 25,
    );

   my $IndentSet = $IndentWin->AddButton(
        -text => "Set",
        -name => "IndentSet",
        -left => 130,
        -top  => 10,
    );

  my $Button=$main_window->AddButton(                     
        -text => 'Create tree',
        -name =>  'treecreate',
        -size => [110,20],
        -align=>center,
        -pos  =>  [135,150],
        -font =>  $font1,
        -background =>  [177,175,175],
        -foreground => [],
        -tabstop => 1,
  );

$main_window->Show();

my $DOS = Win32::GUI::GetPerlWindow();
Win32::GUI::Hide($DOS);
Win32::GUI::Dialog();

sub treecreate_Click{
 for(my $inc=0;$inc>=10;$inc++){
  $TV->InsertItem(
              -text          => 'Root'.$inc,
              -image         => 0,
              -selectedimage => 1,
             );
 }
}
```

after creating tree menu, how to drag and drop the one node position to another position.

Answer (score 0):

Register a handler to respond to onmousedown onmouseup on the tree

when onmousedown, detect which item was selected, then register a handler (closure) that responds to onmousemove

when onmouseup, unregister the handler that responds to onmousemove, detect mouse position, if it was still above tree widget, use api calls to move the previously detected item to new position

you also want to change the curson while dragging

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ROBERTMAY/Win32-GUI-1.06/samples/listview_drag_drop.pl

http://search.cpan.org/src/ROBERTMAY/Win32-GUI-1.06/Win32-GUI-DropFiles/t/08_DragQueryPoint.t

Comment: The above references are not working...
can you please give any example.? I am working with perl under Windows XP.